# Ghost Blogging Platform: Using different template for different categories

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

Is it possible to have different pages for different categories in ghost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Categories in Ghost are called tags, and the details of how to create a template for a particular tag are covered in the documentation for the [tag pages](http://themes.ghost.org/docs/tag-context) and for [templates](http://themes.ghost.org/docs/templates).

To explain, each tag gets a 'slug' which forms the url. E.g. the default tag already included when you install Ghost is 'Getting Started' which has the slug 'getting-started'. The tag page can be accessed at `yourblog.com/tag/getting-started/` and you can create a template for it by using the filename `tag-getting-started.hbs`.

Note: you will need to restart Ghost for it to detect new templates after adding the file.